# Data warehouse design shared branch scenario

Tags: sql, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Let's say we have the following data source view for one of the cube. The Fact table it's in the middle and relates the amount /branch/cost center/Cost category/ date/scenario (current vs budget).

[image: DSV]

The current Amount measure means the value of the 100% of the branch.
 But in my scenario, the company has branches that are owned only by a percent, not 100%. 
 An example:
      BranchNo 7 was owned 50% from the Amount until january 2013, 80% from january 2013 until january 2014 and 100% until today.
      This information it's keept in a table like the one below. The table stores the history of the SharePercent changes...

Fk_branch, FK_Date, SharePercent

7,   201301,  80.000
7,   201401 ,  100

Wich is the best approach to integrate this in the schema presented in the link above? I think about a new measured called SharedAmount, but how should the deisgn looks like given the table of sharings ?

Comment: Just few questions. You guys ever have one amount percent per Branch? Does it change frequently? What are you thinking to put into if you create a new measure table?

Comment: Hi, the percentage can be changed 1 or 2 time per year. There is no month where a branch has 2 percent. I have the amount of the branch if the branch were 100% , so i think i need just to apply that percentage on the 100% amount depending on the changes of the percent in the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding a new measure in the fact table called SharedAmount. The shares are calculated in the fact table during the ETL Process as being Amount(100%) * SharePercent saved in the Branch Dimension for a given period.